# C# Unity - How To Parse a Steam News Page to Extract an IMG URL? The Data received from the Get Resquest seems incomplete. Is it XHTML?

Tags: c#, parsing, xml-parsing, xhtml, html-parsing

## Problem:

I am having trouble trying to parse this page for the enclosure xml tags that contain image links.

https://store.steampowered.com/feeds/news/app/1348750/?cc=US&l=english&snr=1_2108_9__2107

I am using Unity and C#, I get the data either in Encoded UTF-8 string, or raw byte[] from unitys UnityWebRequest.Get method.

When saving to file, or printing to a text box, it seems that a lot of the data is jumbled.

I believe the data is suppose to be XHTML, and Im not sure how to get it into the readable format to start parsing the URLs.

## Expectation:

```
<item>
      <title>Update v1.3</title>
      <description>Changelog:&lt;br&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;bb_ul&quot;&gt;&lt;li&gt;Arry and Miri can now gain affection.&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;The player can now view Arry and Miri's epilogue scenes. (You will have to answer their proposal one more time.)&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;The Arry and Miri achievements have been fixed and should unlock when you reach the epilogue.&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;The ability management backend has been 100% REDONE, and all associated bugs should be fixed.&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Specifically, ability use counts and levels will no longer reset if they're no longer in a player preset.&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;bb_h2&quot;&gt;ACTION REQUIRED:&lt;/div&gt;If you take one thing from this update, it's that &lt;b&gt;Arry and Miri's&lt;/b&gt; conversation lines were &lt;b&gt;broken&lt;/b&gt; before this update, with all their epilogue scenes being &lt;b&gt;hidden&lt;/b&gt;. &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;If you've been stuck at their proposal, doing it one more time should unlock their achievements and lead you to their epilogue scenes.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Additionally, I've begun work on the logbook! It's coming along nicely.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;https://i.imgur.com/FBdDow9.png&quot; /&gt;</description>
      <link><![CDATA[https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1348750/view/3178989079011859448]]></link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 10 May 2022 02:28:06 +0000</pubDate>
      <author>niku_treat</author>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1348750/view/3178989079011859448</guid>
      <enclosure url="https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/clans/38198503/25733639d563297f7a04c4fd68537f5b9aba3d67.png" length="0" type="image/png" />
    </item>
```

## Actual:

These are just snippets from the data, top being some of the HTML it was able to show, and the bottom looking like maybe the XML portion or XHTML?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html class=" responsive" lang="en"&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
    &lt;meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"&gt;
            &lt;meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"&gt;
        &lt;meta name="theme-color" content="#171a21"&gt;
        &lt;title&gt;Hearts of the Dungeon List - Steam News Hub&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"&gt;
```

```
ot;:&amp;quot;Changelog:\n[list]\n[*]Arry and Miri can now gain affection.\n[*]The player can now view Arry and Miri's epilogue scenes. (You will have to answer their proposal one more time.)\n[*]The Arry and Miri achievements have been fixed and should unlock when you reach the epilogue.\n[*]The ability management backend has been 100% REDONE, and all associated bugs should be fixed.\n[*]Specifically, ability use counts and levels will no longer reset if they're no longer in a player preset.\n[\/list]\n\n[h2]ACTION REQUIRED:[\/h2]\nIf you take one thing from this update, it's that [b]Arry and Miri's[\/b] conversation lines were [b]broken[\/b] before this update, with all their epilogue scenes being [b]hidden[\/b]. \n\n[b]If you've been stuck at their proposal, doing it one more time should unlock their achievements and lead you to their epilogue scenes.[\/b]\n\nAdditionally, I've begun work on the logbook! It's coming along nicely.\n\n[img]https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/FBdDow9.png[\/img]&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;commentcount&amp;quot;:1,&amp;quot;tags&amp;quot;:[&amp;quot;mod_reviewed&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;ModAct_870845553_1652150701_0&amp;quot;],&amp;quot;language&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;forum_topic_id&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;3274690571081137373&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;event_gid&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;3178989079011859448&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;voteupcount&amp;quot;:11,&amp;quot;votedowncount&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;ban_check_result&amp;quot;:0},&amp;quot;published&amp;quot;:1,&amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;rtime32_visibility_start&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;rtime32_visibility_end&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;broadcaster_accountid&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;follower_count&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;ignore_count&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;forum_topic_id&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;3274690571081137373&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;rtime32_last_modified&amp;quot;:1653189104,&amp;quot;news_post_gid&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;rtime_mod_reviewed&amp;quot;:1652150697,&amp;quot;featured_app_tagid&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;referenced_appids&amp;quot;:[],&amp;quot;build_id&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;build_branch&amp;quot
```

## Example Code

```
public static IEnumerator GetCoroutine(string url, Action<string> OnError, Action<string> OnSuccess)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest result = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return result.SendWebRequest();

            if (result.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || result.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
            {
                OnError(result.error);
            }
            else
            {
                string rawUTF8Text = result.downloadHandler.text;

                FileStream file;
                string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/xmlsave.xml";
                file = File.Create(filePath);
                
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(file, rawUTF8Text);

                file.Close();

                OnSuccess(rawUTF8Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The page you linked to is an XML RSS Atom feed.  There is no need for you to manually grep the XML, just use XDocument or XmlReader or some other XML parser.

Comment: I added a code example of how I am printing the return GET body to a file?

So do I have to turn the UTF8 Text into a Xdocument? then parse the info I want out of it?

Comment: Use XDocument doc = xDocument.Parse(string);